# Android socket programming emulator connection fault

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am writing a server client application on android for my internship project. All of the client can send message eachothers with server permission on the local host. First of all i wrote server and client side but i cant connect emulator on the local host and ı have to run all emulator on the same computer. I examine other question and answers but they dont work for me. My question is how to connect emulators(clients and server) with eachothers?I tried 10.0.2.2 and redirecting port but doesnt work. Can anobody help me just a simple project connect client and server and send and recieve just a simple string?thanks a lots....

Comment: Does it work to let one client communicate with the server?

Comment: No it doesnt. I cant connect even one client to server. ı wrote all of the code if ı can conect project will work but ı cant make a connection. on the server side listening the port but on the client side
String adress = "10.0.2.2"; 
InetAdress mdr = InetAdress.getByName(address);
Socket socket = new Socket(mdr,PORTNO);
lines doesnt work. last line (new socket) does not create socket. so ı cant connect to the server

Comment: Did you checked firewall settings? And some code of the client and server (connection) might help as well if it isn't a firewall problem.

Comment: actually ı am working on a privicy safe network company. So there can be some firewall but i cant change because of premission. İf ı can connect and just send even a string it will going on but now ı cant connect. I wanna share my code but ı hace 5-6 classes ont he both server and client side.

Comment: Try to make a simple android app which connects to a simple server with a window so you can see what is coming in and going out on both sides with the Sockets. Normally it should work (if firewall allows it).

Comment: ı do all thing but dowsnt work you should probably wright it is about firewall. At this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693063/android-socket-programming-emulator-communication  they explain good and ı do. Can you try this project at this link and can you make sure if it is working for you? if it is working we can make sure the problem abouth the firewall.

Comment: I cannot try it out because I do not have any Android environment here at the PC, I'm sorry. But I should propose that you contact your system administrator to let you be able to control your local firewall so you can test the application correctly.

Comment: This is an military company and this is not possible but thanks for your advice:D i wiil try until my internship is ower. thanks alot.